# Use existing windows mobile 5 app for making android app

Tags: android

I have to develop android app which is already made for windows mobile 5 using Visual Studio with C# language. So is there any way to use this existing code to build android app?

Anybody knows how to use Rhomobile framework which is used to create multiplatform applications?

Answer (score 0):

I would give [mono for android](http://android.xamarin.com/%22Mono%20for%20android%22) a try.

Answer (score 0):

> So is there any way to use this existing code to build android app?

Nope... sorry. Two different languages. Plus a lot has moved on since Windows Mobile 5! You'll probably want to make something a bit more modern.

> Anybody knows how to use Rhomobile framework which is used to create multiplatform applications?

That's a very broad question, one which can't really be answered here. What I would suggest is having a look at [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/). It has its own syntax in a javascript-esque style and its pretty good for cross platform apps. Its not as powerful or as diverse as creating apps from scratch natively in each language but its still pretty good, well worth looking into.